# UWP - Creating a data bound tooltip on an image in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, tooltip, win-universal-app

I have a data driven hub section that is populating the image just fine. The view model contains text I would like to show as a tooltip, but can't quite figure it out.

Here's the important snippet:

```
<HubSection x:Uid="MyHub" x:Name="MyHubSection" Width="311">
   <HubSection.Header>
      <TextBlock x:Uid="HubMSectionHeader" 
                 Style="{StaticResource MainHubSectionHeaderStyle}" Text="Friends"/>
   </HubSection.Header>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <Button x:Name="InviteButton" Content="Send Invite" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="InviteButton_Click"/>
         <StackPanel >
            <Grid>
               <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}"  Background="{ThemeResource HubBackground}" x:Name="FriendGrid" >
                   <GridView.ItemTemplate >
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <Image Source="{Binding ProfilePhotoBitmap, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Opacity="1" Stretch="Uniform" Tapped="Friend_Tapped"/>
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                  </GridView>
               </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am wondering why the Tooltip service code is outside of the image control could you try inside image control and let me know whether it works or not?
modified code snipet will be

```
<Image Source="{Binding ProfilePhotoBitmap, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Opacity="1" Stretch="Uniform" Tapped="Friend_Tapped">
            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </Image>
```

Comment: Oooh, I didn't even notice that! +1

Comment: Thanks. That was it!