# ToolTipService.ToolTip not working on DataGridCell in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

i'm trying to display a tooltip over a cell in a Windows Toolkit DataGrid in UWP XAML.
I'm able to show a static value by doing this:

```
<wct:DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding ChargeInformationDto.Description, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Navn" Tag="Description">
    <wct:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="wct:DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="Tooltip text to show" />
        </Style>
    </wct:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</wct:DataGridTextColumn>
```

But with Bindings it does not show:

```
<wct:DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding ChargeInformationDto.Description, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Navn" Tag="Description">
    <wct:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="wct:DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding ChargeInformationDto.Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
    </wct:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</wct:DataGridTextColumn>
```

Anyone managed to make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011011/uwp-creating-a-data-bound-tooltip-on-an-image-in-xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP XAML, you cannot use binding in Style. For specific instructions, please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041#migration-notes):

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Microsoft Silverlight supported the ability to use a Binding expression to supply the Value for a Setter in a Style. The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding usage for Setter.Value (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result either).

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridTextColumn.cs#L215) of `DataGridTextColumn`, `DataGridTextColumn` will dynamically create a `TextBlock` and `TextBox` to display and edit content, so using `TooltipService` directly in the XAML to set `Tooltip` will not be attached to the newly created `TextBlock`, which is the reason of Tooltip cannot be displayed.

If you want to display Tooltip, then you can consider creating a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```xml
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="200"
                                  Header="Navn" Tag="Description">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChargeInformationDto.Description, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20"
                       ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ChargeInformationDto.Description, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It works, thank you for your help @richard.
Have a great day!

Comment: so why those properties are event settable ? for this is a bug in the design and I just wasted some ours trying to set this using style :(  I am wondering how such piece of code manages to be release to public are they not running validation test for  each properties etc ?